# T-SQL Replace If Condition For String

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replace

We replace our dynamic sql string,like replace(@sqlString,'dbo',@dbName+'dbo').
And @sqlString may included more than select statement,it could be spesific.

```
original sql : select * from dbo.TableOne
replaced     : select * from HOSTED.dbo.TableOne
```

When contains Db name,we dont want to replace.How to handle it.Is there possible to control like if previous rom dbo characters contains dot character not replace.

Error condition.

```
original sql : select * from HOSTED.dbo.TableOne
replace      : select * from HOSTED.HOSTED.dbo.TableOne
```

**EDIT:**

Why i intent dot charachter,because of sometimes dynamic sql not contain space like that.

```
select * from dbo.TableOne where ColumnOne>=dbo.SpecialFunction.
```

Comment: Try here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You could use [`ParseName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) to separate the parts of the original object name and then reassemble them with a new database name. You can use [`case`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) to handle conditional bits, e.g. NULLs.

Comment: When you edit, please make sure you clearly indicate it so existing answer won't be invalidated.

Comment: @Iad2025,sorry for that.I'm gratefull for your answer,but i need some extra trick to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `REPLACE` with space before `'dbo'`:

```
DECLARE @dbName SYSNAME = 'HOSTED';
DECLARE @sqlString VARCHAR(MAX) = 'select * from dbo.TableOne';

SELECT REPLACE(@sqlString,' dbo',' '+@dbName+'.dbo') AS result

SET @sqlString = 'select * from HOSTED.dbo.TableOne';
SELECT REPLACE(@sqlString,' dbo',' '+@dbName+'.dbo') AS result
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/451983?opt.textResults=true)**</kbd>

Be aware that if `@dbName` will be `NULL` entire `@sqlString` will be `NULL`.

**EDIT:**

You could use multiple `REPLACE` (you should handle `>`,`=`,`(`,...):

```
DECLARE @dbName SYSNAME = 'HOSTED';
DECLARE @sqlString VARCHAR(MAX) 
        = 'select * from dbo.TableOne where ColumnOne>=dbo.SpecialFunction.';

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@sqlString,'=dbo','='+@dbName+'.dbo')
               ,' dbo',' '+@dbName+'.dbo') AS result
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/452293)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks for helpfully answer,this solution provide most of the issues,but we stored dynamicSql sometimes doesnt include space like,select * from dbo.TableOne where columnOne>=dbo.SpecialFunction,if it is like doesnt replace.How to handle it.I want to get like that select * from HOSTED.dbo.TableOne where columnOne=HOSTED.dbo.TableOne.

Comment: In that case you need to use multiple replace and search from `>`, `>=`, `=`,`(` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how to distinguish between the `dbo.someTable` and the `someDB.dbo.someTable` and replace a `dbo` only with the first one. You can do it with a little trick by escaping the `.dbo` like in this code

```
declare @sqlString nvarchar(max) = N'select * from dbo.TableOne where HOSTED.dbo.TableOne.somefield = someValue';
declare @dbName nvarchar(max) = N'HOSTED';

-- replace '.dbo' with something else like for example incorrect variable name
set @sqlString = replace (@sqlString, N'.dbo', N'@._d_b_o');

-- add database name before 'dbo.'
set @sqlString = replace(@sqlString, N'dbo.', concat(@dbName,N'.dbo.'));

-- restore escaped '.dbo' to original value
set @sqlString = replace (@sqlString, N'@._d_b_o', N'.dbo');

select @sqlString;
```

The code above will return

> select * from HOSTED.dbo.TableOne where HOSTED.dbo.TableOne.somefield = someValue

This solution will work even if you have no space before dbo like in this string

> select * from dbo.TableOne where ColumnOne>=dbo.SpecialFunction

When you are using the `replace` function you have to be aware about case sensitivity so if you need to use case insensitive replace then check examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx).